# Extract bit range from byte array and create a new int

Tags: c, endianness

I need to extract bits from a byte array (little endian), and then form a new int from it.

Say my byte array is this:

`[0b00011001, 0b11001001, 0b00101010, 0b11001110]`

And I need to extract bits 14 to 18 (inclusive).

First I bitmask like so:

`[0b00011001, 0b11000000, 0b00000010, 0b11001110]` using `& 0b11000000` on `[1]` and `& 0b00000111` on `[2]`

Then remove first byte, and reset other bytes:

`[0b11000000, 0b00000010, 0b00000000, 0b00000000]`

If I form an uint 32 out of this, it results in `704`. Is this correct?

Is assuming MSB = 7 and LSB = 0 correct?

Comment: It would be easier to put all four bytes into an unsigned integer (presuming 32bit ints), then mask for only those you want to retain? Why fiddle about with fragments?

Comment: @Fe2O3 Wouldn't all the bits be offset giving me a higher number?

Comment: Bits 14 to 18 would be 5 bits: 14,15,16,17,18. The maximum value for a 5-bit number is 31. So 704 is definitely not correct.

Comment: As far as I can tell the answer would be `01011` which is 11

Comment: @Fe2O3 I want all other bits to be ignored and form an int only assuming my bit range exists

Comment: @Fe2O3 No, there wasn't a direct mention of shift but to me *"extract bits 14 to 18"* means take those bits and forget the rest. And that's the only thing that makes sense if you consider arrays being more than 8 bytes.

Comment: The word "extract" is open to interpretation. And the phrase "little endian" is also ambiguous, since it can refer to byte ordering, or bit ordering, or both. So OP needs to talk to the person who assigned this task, and get a precise definition of which bits are which, and what the output is supposed to be.

Comment: @t348575 In you example you correctly got rid of the whole first byte. However you did not get rid of the first 6 bits in the second byte. That's why you got the wrong result. Notice that `704 >> 6 = 11`

Comment: @user3386109 the byte ordering is little endian. I dont know about the bits. Usually is MSB 7 and LSB 0 or?

Comment: @t348575 Correct. That's how it works for little endian. Array index 0 is the least significant byte. Inside that byte bit 0 is the list significant bit and bit 7 is the most significant bit. That's why a direct raw ascending memory dump on a little endian machine is somewhat hard to read.

Comment: @t348575 What kind of answer are you looking for? An explanation of the basic bit-manipulation or an algorithm or some code? If you are looking for code, you should start by posting your own attempt to solve the task so we have that as a starting point. In general we don't write code from scratch...

Comment: @t348575 You have to ask the person that gave you the task. They know which bit they define as 14 and which bit is 18. Everybody here is just guessing.

Comment: @user3386109 I don't think there are any "guessing" involved when it comes to bit numbers and byte numbers. It's standard little endian. No surprises.

Comment: @t348575 Is the array **always** 4 bytes or can it have any size?

Comment: @SupportUkraine I posted like a minimal question here, I actually will have N size array, as input, and then I have a template function to parse and return to a given type (u8, u16, 32 64 etc.) I already figured that out, just had issues with the actual bit manipulation logic. But Fe2O3's edit answers the question ig.

Comment: @t348575 Well if the answer from Fe2O3 helped you solve your problem, it's great. Type punning using a union as suggested by the answer is however problematic for several reasons. For instance when you want to extract bits from 2 to 33. But again... if you found a solution, great.

Comment: @t348575 BTW: If you had provided the information from your last comment from the start (i.e. as part of the question) a lot of confusion would have been avoided. It's true that SO prefers minimal descriptions but take care that it doesn't become so "minimal" that important information is lost. Just an advice for your next question. Have fun.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it would be much easier to work with a `union`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef union {
    uint32_t i;
    uint8_t c[4];
} u_t;

int main( void ) {
    u_t u = { 0 };

    // Little Endian machine
    u.c[0] = 0x19; // I believe these are the hex equivalent of OP data.
    u.c[1] = 0xC9;
    u.c[2] = 0x2A;
    u.c[3] = 0xCE;

    u.i &= 0x1F << (14-1); // Mask for 5 bits, b14-b18

    printf( "%08X\n", u.i );
    printf( "%u\n", u.i );

    printf( "%u\n", u.i >> 8 ); // my (our) mistake

    printf( "%u\n", u.i >> 14 ); // Perhaps what was intended

    return 0;
}
```

```
0002C000
180224
704
11
```

Of course, this would be much simpler just shifting the value to the right to begin with, then mask for the 5 lowest bits... C'est la guerre...